# Flutter dart call super of super class method

Tags: flutter, dart, super

Here is my architecture, I have two statfull widgets: `ProfilePicture, RoundedProfilePicture`. `ProfilePicture` is a statefull widget and it has complicated custom code which is very prone to error so I dont want to copy paste it, it utilizes variables from `Picture` abstract class. (ie. fetches server data and stores them inside variables of `Picture`). What I want to do is I want to extend from this widgets state so that I can create a new widget `RoundedProfilePicture`. This widgets state will basically utilize the complicated code from `ProfilePicture`'s state with inheritance and it will add small extra logic to it. So I thought inheritance is the best choice here. Here is what I tried so far

```
class ProfilePictureState extends State<ProfilePicture> implements Picture{
    // SOME LONG COMPLICATED 500 LINE OF CODE
}

class RoundedProfilePictureState extends ProfilePictureState {
    @override
    void initState() {
       super.initState(); // this calls ProfilePictureState.initState() call. I want to call State<ProfilePicture>.initState()
    }
 }
```

My problem is void `initState()` in `RoundedProfilePictureState` requires me to make a `super.initState()` call. This call makes a `ProfilePictureState.initState()` call. I want to call `State<ProfilePicture>.initState()` because I want to add a different logic in my init state call. So the structure is:

```
----abstract State class
---ProfilePictureState 
--RoundedProfilePictureState
```

How can I make a call to abstract State class's `initState` method from `RoundedProfilePictureState`? Is this possible?

Comment: If you have to call super-super, the hierarchy is mis-designed.  calling super means "I'm just like my parent class, except I add this additional behavior".  If you ever need to ignore parent class, and skip to grandparent class, something is very wrong.

Comment: Agreed. My hierarchy design was flawed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, here is how I solved this. I think this is impossible to achieve. What I did is I moved the code and all the variables to a `mixin`. Took like an hour or two to do so. I achieved my needs tho.